# Getting all parameter names using C++

Tags: ros, rosparam, parameter, server, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am developing an application where I need to get all the parameter names from the parameter server (without specifically knowing the names of each parameter). I have only seen it possible on python using "getParamNames(caller_id)", but is something similar possible using C++?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9593/getting-all-parameter-names-using-c++/) by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2011-03-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get arbitrarily complex data structures off the parameter server using the XMLRPC data structure.

See
[bool ros::NodeHandle::getParam(const std::string & key, XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue & ) const](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#abc94604759c310c72e1b2d34b656755c) in the API docs.

The only downside is that you have to use XMLRPC data types manipulation.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on 2011-04-05**:
Thanks, might be an option. I late also found out that it is not totally easy to figure out data types in C++ from a random variable, so I think Python does things pretty smooth and easy. Due to the simplicity of the program, then I do not expect the big overhead in using it over C++.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there is direct support for this by roscpp, so you probably have to query the parameter server directly. You can have a look at the [Parameter Server API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Parameter%20Server%20API) and at the file `roscpp/src/libros/param.cpp` for an idea how to do that.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1